# Run curl command in gradle at a specific point in time

Tags: android, curl, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard, bugsnag

I use bugsnag to monitor crashes in my Android app.
I also use ProGuard when I compile a release version.
I need to upload the mapping.txt file that is generated in build/outputs/mapping/prod/release folder of my project.

When I run this command in (Windows) command line:

```
curl https://upload.bugsnag.com -F proguard=@C:/mapping.txt -F apiKey=1111111111111111111111 -F versionCode=11111111 -F appId=com.my.package -F versionNumber=1.0.0
```

The file is uploaded and everything works.

All I need is to add a task to gradle so it uploads the file once its ready.
So once I compile the project for release, the mapping.txt file gets generated and once its ready, upload the file using this curl command ([which is taken from bugsnag's web site by the way](https://bugsnag.com/docs/notifiers/android/proguard)).

I tried many variations. The current one compiles but I do not think the file is being uploaded... I can't see any indication that it actually happened.
This is the code I currently use:

```
task uploadPro(type: Exec) {
    logger.error("inside upload task")
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'curl', 'https://upload.bugsnag.com', '-F','proguard=@build/outputs/mapping/prod/release/mapping.txt', '-F', 'apiKey=1111111111111111111111', '-F', 'versionCode=111111', '-F', 'appId=com.my.package', '-F', 'versionNumber=1.0.0'
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    doLast {
        String output = standardOutput.toString()
        logger.info(output);
    }
}
```

I also tried using this:

```
def p = ['cmd', '/c', 'curl', 'https://upload.bugsnag.com', '-F', 'proguard=@build/outputs/mapping/prod/release/mapping.txt', '-F', 'apiKey=11111111111111111111111', '-F', 'versionCode=1111111', '-F', 'appId=com.my.package', '-F', 'versionNumber=1.0.0'].execute()
```

The way I call this task is by using this command:

```
tasks.getByName("assembleRelease").finalizedBy(uploadPro)
```

Im really not sure how to do this. Any help is appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe just this might be enough:  `assembleRelease.finalizedBy uploadPro`

Comment: Well the uploadPro task does work. I can see the "inside upload task" getting printed in Gradle Console. So Im sure the code is reached. But Im not sure if the way I run the curl command is correct... In Windows cmd, when I run this command and it is successful I see a result text: OK. If I fail I see the error text. How can I get those in gradle? And how can I make sure this is called AFTER the mapping.txt file is generated and not before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question... mostly. Here is the code I use to run the curl command at the end of the build process:

```
task uploadPro << {
    logger.error("Uploading mapping.txt file to bugsnag")
    def myCommand = "cmd /c curl https://upload.bugsnag.com -F proguard=@path\\to\mappingFile\\mapping.txt -F " +
        "apiKey=111111111111111111111111 -F versionCode=" + versionCodeId + " -F " +
        "appId=com.xxxx.yyy.zzz -F versionNumber=" + versionId
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(myCommand.split(' '));
    Process process = builder.start();
    process.waitFor()
    println process.err.text
    println process.text
}
```

Then I use this to run it at the end of the build process:

```
gradle.buildFinished {
    tasks.uploadPro.execute()
}
```

Cant be sure this is best practice but it works.

I would have liked to run the uploadPro task ONLY during a release buildType...but this proves to be difficult as well.

Comment: What if argument have spaces like `Authorization:Bearer ehfh...` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75789954/auth-token-error-in-curl-command-in-gradle

Comment: what about something like:

`tasks.register('callBugsnagNpmScript', Exec) {
        // do work
}`
and then

`tasks.getByName('assembleRelease').finalizedBy(tasks.getByName('callBugsnagNpmScript'))`