# Auth token error in curl command in gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, curl

I tried below code in my Springboot microservice application within `build.gradle`

```
def myCommand = "curl -X GET http://localhost:8405/my-accounts " +
                "-H Authorization:'Bearer JSUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImIwZWM2ODhhZjAzZGQ3ODc1MTE2YmY2ZDM2YzM1MDIwODg2ZTQ4ODIifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJSM0NJU1VTRVIyIiwiYWNyIjoiSUFMMi5BQUwzLkZBTDEiLCJhdWQiOlsiVEJPUyJdLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJSM0NJU1VTRVIyIiwib20iLCJ4LXdkLXVzZXJ0eXBlIjoiRVhURVJOQUwiLCJzY29wZXMiOlsiQUxMLklOU1QtR0JMLlBBWU1FTlQuQUxMIiwiQUxMLklOU1QtR0JMLk9NTklBUFBTLkFMTCIsIkFMTC5JTlNULUdCTC5QUk9GSUxFLkFMTCIsIkFMTC5JTlNULUdCTC5SRVAuQUxMIiwiQUxMLklOU1QtR0JMLlJFQ0VJVkFCTEUuQUxMIiwiQUxMLklOU1QtR0JMLkNBUkQuQUxMIl0sImV4cCI6MjI4NDk3NTcxMzUzOCwibm9uY2UiOiJUQk9TIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiVEJPUyJ9.DS8YTDoNGS2xG_kxbCHGFhoRs3k-0M0IyuIeku-LIXJfqhR5qLRoxW0Za7qV9tn1lPDAnhV0vgvimNqe-4Eb_ZoIiPZL4mHBACS6rhH-bbMIEShfFOerVC20_csr4po0T89t251k4_wxSR557NryxeBtO4QX_sJLthfaVkVS9CngeTOPnc31_wAr33e36KysGlSgDoZMmrwcu7KSYCVMLr2doc5J0wcIcKaK_AAn_bW-ds6UsZpFCXZ1-wIjreoH03GHH8-z9db2Qv6KPJKIOsOxy-0T5n0xXTmJnZHPFDzHHPWktDCxBlqIpWGw-XRBf1U0xtCOPQ' "

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(myCommand.split(' '));
        Process process = builder.start();
        process.waitFor()

        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream()
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout))
        println reader.readLine()
```

And I get below error

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-03-20T11:32:16.866+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "The token was expected to have 3 parts, but got 1.",
  "path": "/my-accounts",
  "errors": [{ "field": "root", "message": "Internal Server Error" }]
}
```

However if I use the same curl in commandline it works. So that means nothing wrong with the token

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8405/dompay-accounts -H Authorization:"Bearer JSUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImIwZWM2ODhhZjAzZGQ3ODc1MTE2YmY2ZDM2YzM1MDIwODg2ZTQ4ODIifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJSM0NJU1VTRVIyIiwiYWNyIjoiSUFMMi5BQUwzLkZBTDEiLCJhdWQiOlsiVEJPUyJdLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJSM0NJU1VTRVIyIiwib20iLCJ4LXdkLXVzZXJ0eXBlIjoiRVhURVJOQUwiLCJzY29wZXMiOlsiQUxMLklOU1QtR0JMLlBBWU1FTlQuQUxMIiwiQUxMLklOU1QtR0JMLk9NTklBUFBTLkFMTCIsIkFMTC5JTlNULUdCTC5QUk9GSUxFLkFMTCIsIkFMTC5JTlNULUdCTC5SRVAuQUxMIiwiQUxMLklOU1QtR0JMLlJFQ0VJVkFCTEUuQUxMIiwiQUxMLklOU1QtR0JMLkNBUkQuQUxMIl0sImV4cCI6MjI4NDk3NTcxMzUzOCwibm9uY2UiOiJUQk9TIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiVEJPUyJ9.DS8YTDoNGS2xG_kxbCHGFhoRs3k-0M0IyuIeku-LIXJfqhR5qLRoxW0Za7qV9tn1lPDAnhV0vgvimNqe-4Eb_ZoIiPZL4mHBACS6rhH-bbMIEShfFOerVC20_csr4po0T89t251k4_wxSR557NryxeBtO4QX_sJLthfaVkVS9CngeTOPnc31_wAr33e36KysGlSgDoZMmrwcu7KSYCVMLr2doc5J0wcIcKaK_AAn_bW-ds6UsZpFCXZ1-wIjreoH03GHH8-z9db2Qv6KPJKIOsOxy-0T5n0xXTmJnZHPFDzHHPWktDCxBlqIpWGw-XRBf1U0xtCOPQ"
```

I tried below different syntax for the auth header as well, but no luck

```
"-H Authorization:'Bearer JSUzUx...'" >> same above error
"-H Authorization:Bearer JSUzUx..."  >> same above error
"-H Authorization:\"Bearer JSUzUx...\"" >> No response/error at all
"-H Authorization:\"'Bearer JSUzUx...'\"" >> No response/error at all
```

Comment: `-h "Authorization: Bearer Xxxxxxxxxx"`

Comment: @1615903 In the `buid.gradle` I have to use escape char`(\)`. So tried this `"-H \"Authorization: Bearer JSUzUx...\""`. But no response or error. just hung there (similar to last two e.g. given in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to get a resolution

```
def token = "JSUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpX...."
def url = "http://localhost:8405/my-accounts"
def proc = ['curl','-X','GET', url, '-H', "Authorization:Bearer ${token}"].execute().text
```

Influnced by this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52411303)